# Definition fields is not the same as field definitions size array

Tags: java, automation

i trying to run the automated script which using java to perform an customerDownload. However the column actualNumFields = 226 but expNumFields = 5 as they trying to compare and im not sure how to solve this. Kindly advise below is my code :

```
protected void populateFields(L msgLine, List<String> values) throws FieldNotFoundException, ParseException, InvalidValueException {
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        if (expectAllFields) {
            int expNumFields = this.fieldDefinitions.length;
            int actualNumFields = values.size();
            Preconditions.checkArgument(actualNumFields == expNumFields, "Values list of size " + actualNumFields
                                                                         + " is not the same as field definitions size "
                                                                         + expNumFields);
        }
        int idx = 0;
        FieldParser parser = (FieldParser) getSerializationContext().getFieldOperator();
        for (String strValue : values) {
            FieldDefinition fDefinition = fieldDefinitions[idx];
            parser.parseStringAndSetValue(msgLine, fDefinition.getFieldName(), strValue);
            idx++;
        }
    }


public TextToMessageLineFactory(DelimitedFileSerializationContext<L> serializationContext) {
        ;
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(serializationContext, "serialization context cannot be null");
        this.serializationContext = serializationContext;
        this.structure = serializationContext.getMessageStructure();
        this.messageLineClass = this.structure.getMessageLineClass();
        this.expectAllFields = serializationContext.isExpectAllFields();
        FieldDefinitionsProvider fieldDefinitionsProvider = this.serializationContext.getFieldDefinitionsProvider();
        fieldDefinitionsProvider = fieldDefinitionsProvider == null ? FieldDefinitionsProvider.ALL_FIELDS_DEFINITIONS_BY_INDEX_PROVIDER
                                                                   : fieldDefinitionsProvider;
        this.fieldDefinitions = fieldDefinitionsProvider.getFieldDefinitions(structure);
    }
```

The fields of definitionProvider will be :

```
public FieldDefinition[] getFieldDefinitions(MessageLineStructure<? extends MessageLine> mls);

    // @formatter:off
    public static final FieldDefinitionsProvider 
        ALL_FIELDS_DEFINITIONS_BY_INDEX_PROVIDER = 
                    new FieldDefinitionsProvider() {
                      @Override
                      public FieldDefinition[] getFieldDefinitions(MessageLineStructure<? extends MessageLine> mls) {
                          Preconditions.checkNotNull(mls,
                                                     "Message line structure cannot be null");
                          List<FieldDefinition> fieldDefinitions = mls.getFieldDefinitions(FieldDefinition.ByIndexComparator);
                          return fieldDefinitions.toArray(new FieldDefinition[fieldDefinitions.size()]);
                      }
                  };
```

Comment: The error getting was : "Values list of size "  226 is not the same as field definitions size  5)

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect us do solve this... we don't know *why* there are 226 values when there are only 5 fields... we have no idea what has written this data, what `FieldDefinitionsProvider` is etc.